# Roll up one hot encoded columns into their various columns based on column names

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame that is already one-hot encoded. The column names of the hot encoded columns, start with the main column name plus _ then the particular class of that column. For example, if a column is of gender, and the values in the column are male and female, the hot encoded columns, are gender_male, gender_female. So now I want to roll it back to the main column, where I would have gender, and each row depending would have male or female. An example can be seen in the image [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XykIL.png)

Comment: Hi and welcome on SO. It will be great if you can have a look at [how-to-ask](/help/how-to-ask) and then try to produce a [mcve](/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

One idea is split by last `_` to `MultiIndex` and then use [`DataFrame.dot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dot.html) per first level of `MultiIndex`:

```
df.columns = df.columns.str.rsplit('_', n=1, expand=True)

def f(x):
    y = x.droplevel(0, axis=1)
    return y.dot(y.columns)

df = df.groupby(level=0, axis=1).apply(f)
```